# Command findAndModify failed: Modification of or using Decimal128 values is not supported

Tags: mongodb, azure-cosmosdb, mongodb-.net-driver, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I can't find any documentation anywhere that highlights that Cosmos DB (Mongo Api) doesn't support $inc on the BSON Decimal type.

**Replicating the issue**

The following query fails against a Cosmos DB (Mongo Api) - for both 3.6 and 4.0 mongo db server versions:

```
db.myCollection.findAndModify({
   query: { _id: "a-document-id" },
   update: { $inc: { myDecimal : NumberDecimal("-1.05") } },
   new: true
})
```

Here's a document you can use the query above against:

```
{
    "_id" : "a-document-id",
    "myDecimal" : {
        "$numberDecimal" : "5"
    }
}
```

**The story behind it**

I'm trying to increment a decimal value (it has the `BsonRepresentation(BsonType.Decimal128)` attribute), I'm using the MongoDB .Net driver (v2.11.6) to do so using an update definition like so:

```
var update = Builders<Models.MyObject>.Update.Inc(w => w.MyDecimal, command.DecimalToAddOn)

return await _mongoCollection.FindOneAndUpdateAsync(w => w.Id == myDocumentId, update);
```

I get this error when passing my update along with a simple expression that has the document id matched on it.

```
MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException: Command findAndModify failed: Modification of or using Decimal128 values is not supported..
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandUsingCommandMessageWireProtocol`1.ProcessResponse(ConnectionId connectionId, CommandMessage responseMessage)
```

The database itself is a Cosmos DB (Mongo API) with the Mongo DB server version set to 3.6.

Before there are any comments on representing certain values in decimals, it's recommended by MongoDB for money, so it can be used for other similar properties too - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-monetary-data/

Comment: The same issue occurs for this query too:

`db.myCollection.update({_id:"an-existing-document-id"}, {$inc: {MyDecimal: -1.05}})`

Comment: I'm new to mongo sir, and I found a [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-feature-support-36) which tells the supported features and syntax, I think if the function is not mentioned in it, it may really haven't supported.

Comment: I have no probs running your  findAndModify (with NumberDecimal) locally (directly from the shell) with mongo 4.4 if it may help

Comment: @grodzi Yeah, we can run it locally against mongo 3.6, unfortunately it looks like it's a cosmos issue. Thanks for checking though :)

Comment: @Tiny-wa unfortunately that document claims to support both $inc and Decimal128 :(

Comment: @LloydPowell Good day sir, have you got any progress? I searched for [docs related](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/tutorial/model-monetary-data/) to mongodb and find that the documents stored in db is like '{ "_id" : 5, , "price" : NumberLong(8000), "priceDec" : NumberDecimal("80.00") }' and the one you provided is ' "$numberDecimal" : "5" ', can this caused the problem?

Comment: @Tiny-wa I don't think so. I've had a reply from Microsoft and contrary to their documentation, Cosmos DB (Mongo API) does not support $inc and $mul on Decimal128 types.

Comment: @LloydPowellOh, that's a pity for not support. Could you pls add this tip as the answer so that it may help others？

Answer (score 1):

I've spoken with someone at Microsoft who has relayed the response from the Cosmos DB project manager to me. They state that $inc and $mul are not supported for Decimal128. The documentation claiming so will be altered but the implementation of this feature is mot definitely on their roadmap and in progress as we speak. Unfortunately with an unknown time scale for delivery.

In the meantime, anyone who has suffered a similar issue, I've submitted an idea for this on the azure feedback portal. If it gains enough vote maybe it's priority will be heightened https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/42880155-support-the-use-of-inc-and-mul-with-decimal128-p